# as mentioned in profile api docs

Tags: linkedin-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-08

as mentioned here we can use https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me this endpoint for get profile details but it is not working.

we can get profile details from this endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me but it is returning following error:-
{
"code": "VERSION_MISSING",
"message": "A version must be present. Please specify a version by adding the LinkedIn-Version header."
}

here is my complete request:-

GET /rest/me HTTP/1.1
X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Authorization: Bearer XXXX
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: xxx-c465-491a-90f1-ca7dxx1bxxx
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Cookie: cookies

Comment: related?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-2023-10#how-your-api-client-should-use-versioning

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `LinkedIn-Version` header in your request there.  The value should be an API version in the format of `YYYYMM` (e.g. `202306`).